# How to combine stats and mapper in streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

```
public static PriceRangeData getCanonicalPriceRange(final ProductData productDataParent) {
    if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(productDataParent.getAggregates())
            && null != productDataParent.getAggregates().get(DtCoreConstants.RANGED_DATA)) {
        final PriceRangeData data = new PriceRangeData();
        final Map<String, Double> mapPrices = productDataParent.getRangeMapPrices();
        final List<ProductData> ranges = (List<ProductData>) productDataParent.getAggregates()
                .get(DtCoreConstants.RANGED_DATA);
        if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(mapPrices)) {
            ranges.stream()
            .map(productData -> getMapUpdatedData(mapPrices, productData));
        }
        final DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = ranges.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(ProductData::getRawPrice));
        if (null != stats) {
            PriceData minPrice = new PriceData();
            minPrice.setValue(new BigDecimal(stats.getMin()));
            data.setMinPrice(minPrice);
            PriceData maxPrice = new PriceData();
            maxPrice.setValue(new BigDecimal(stats.getMax()));
            data.setMaxPrice(maxPrice);
        }
        return data;
    }
    return null;
}

private static ProductData getMapUpdatedData(final Map<String, Double> mapPrices, final ProductData productData) {
    if (mapPrices.containsKey(productData.getCode())) {
        productData.setRawPrice(mapPrices.get(productData.getCode()));
    }
    return productData;
}
```

Is there a way to combine

```
if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(mapPrices)) {
            ranges.stream()
            .map(productData -> getMapUpdatedData(mapPrices, productData));
        }
```

and

```
final DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = ranges.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(ProductData::getRawPrice));
```

by referring to a local method for getRawPrice rather than ProductData.getRawPrice. Currently we are updating the rawPrice to the ones from mapPrice  if they exist and then redoing the stream for stats. Is there a way to do it without having to update first, rather just use the local method to input the values to compute stats in summarizingDouble

Like using below in Collectors.summarizingDouble method

```
private Double getRawPrice(final Map<String, Double> mapPrices, final ProductData productData) {
        if (mapPrices.containsKey(productData.getCode())) {
            return mapPrices.get(productData.getCode());
        }
        return productData.getRawPrice();
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the following:
`final DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = ranges.stream()
            .map(productData -> getMapUpdatedData(mapPrices, productData)).collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(ProductData::getRawPrice));` ? In theory you will both update your product data elements via the map and then collect the updated statistics. You will simply need to take into account that some of your product data elements will not be updated, but from my understanding this is legit when generating the statistics.

Comment: @RannLifshitz - Thanks. I was wondering how this can achieved without updating the list and using rawprice while computing stats - say a local method getRawPrice that returns double based on whether mapPrices have the value or not. Updated the question with that detail.

Comment: This method simply is doing to much in one. A method should only do either, update existing objects or calculate a new value. Further, you should stop duplicating your code, like invoking `getAggregates()` three times. Then, `if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(mapPrices)) { ranges.stream() .map(productData -> getMapUpdatedData(mapPrices, productData)); }` has no effect on anything. Further, the `DoubleSummaryStatistics` returned by the collector is never `null`, there is no need to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you need

```
 ranges.stream()
        .map(productData -> mapPrices.getOrDefault(productData.getCode(), productData.getRawPrice())) 
        .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(x->x));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works. So you have converted productdata stream into double stream instead of another productdata stream and then applied stats on that.